# How does the left hand operand cout is passed here?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

ostream & currency(ostream & output)
{
    output << "RS ";
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    cout << currency  << 7864.5;
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
 RS 7864.5
```

I don't understand how this seems to work i.e just the name of the function `currency`
is used to invoke the function.
isn't this supposed to be like `currency(cout)` but using it gives output.

```
 RS 1054DBCC7864.5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function `currency()` is a *manipulator*: The stream classes have special overloaded output operators taking functions with a specific sigunature as argument. They look something like this (with the templatization elided):

```
class std::ostream
    public std::ios {
public:
     // ...
     std::ostream& operator<< (std::ios_base& (*manip)(std::ios_base&));            
     std::ostream& operator<< (std::ios& (*manip)(std::ios&));         
     std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& (*manip)(std::ostream&));
};
```

That is, `currency` is passed as a function pointer which gets called with the stream as its argument.

Answer (score 2):

This works (the code in the question):

```
std::cout << currency << 7864.5;
```

So does this:

```
currency(std::cout) << 7864.5;
```

What you evidently tried and complained about, but didn't show, is this:

```
std::cout << currency(std::cout) << 7864.5;
```

That's the same as:

```
ostream& retval = currency(std::cout); // prints "RS " as you expect
std::cout << retval; // oops, this is cout << cout, which is meaningless
std::cout << 7864.5; // prints "7864.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is being treated as an ostream manipulator.